# Getting NSData from a url works in the simulator but not on a device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nsdata, nsurl

I implement a method that send notes to the server:

```
-(IBAction)inserttotextfied:(id)sender{

    NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/get-data/insert.php?Name=%@&message=%@",txtf.text,txt2.text];
    NSData *dataurl=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strurl]];
    NSString *stresult=[[[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataurl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%a",stresult);
}
```

The problem is when I test it via simulator the is being sent, but when I test it in the device the data did  not being saved

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to send something to localhost on your device, or do you use a different url on the device build?

Comment: Have you tried to access the url in Safari on the device? Then you might be able to see if the device can reach the server in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Simulator is faster in response. So the url return data and print properly. But on device the response time is higher then simulator. Your NSLog(@"%a",stresult); statement is executing before it get any data from the response. I will suggest to give some delay or use delegate so that you can use data after getting the response.

Answer (score 0):

Format Specifier `%a` is `64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in scientific notation with a leading 0x and one hexadecimal digit before the decimal point using a lowercase p to introduce the exponent.`

if that is not your intent, try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", stresult);
```